# In-browser painting app

Tags: php, images, api, free

I want to offer visitors of my site an *in-browser drawing app*.

Which apis help me doing that *for free* and *easily* without showing too much of it's origin like by using a link or a huge ad of the service?

Additionally it should be possible to *save the result as image* and to interact with it via *PHP*.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading 'canvas' image data to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [the HTML5 Canvas object](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) (or you'll need something written in Flash or java).

> possible to save the result as image and to interact with it via PHP

Meaning you want to save it serverside - which is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server